# Цикл выдает на одну строку меньше

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Данная конструкция выдает на один пост меньше при подзагрузке. Сразу на index.php загружается первые 5 постов, потом через ajax догружаются еще. AJAX обращается к action.php Получается что-то вроде header24, header23, header22, header21, header20 загружаются сразу (при открытии страницы), при нажатии на кнопку "Загрузить еще" загружаются посты header18, header17, header16, header15. Куда пропадает header19?

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/S1i6mY6z)

[action.php](http://pastebin.com/SFUJvhan)

Проверить, как работает можно [здесь](http://blog.kottsov.ru)

Comment: Может в БД и нет его?)) Может эти данные, табличку выложите? например на http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Весь код, относящийся к вопросу должен быть в вопросе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас не правильная пагинация. `Offset` в `MySQL` должен принимать значение равное `(количеству показанных записей - 1)`.

Добавьте в `actions.php` `-1` при инициализации переменной `$num`:

```
$num = (int) $_GET['num'] - 1;
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, а не подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы кнопка "загрузить еще" не появлялась в последнем блоке постов?

Comment: @АндрейИванов подскажу. Вам тогда нужно отрефакторить ваш код для работы с `json` и тогда вместе с `html` передавать кол-во оставшихся записей. А на клиенте проверять каждый раз это кол-во и соответственно деактивировать кнопку.

Comment: @АндрейИванов если ответ решил вашу проблему, слева есть галочка, что бы отметить ответ как правильный.